# Search performance of Sphinx vs. Haystack

Tags: full-text-search, django-haystack, xapian, django-sphinx

I was wondering if anyone had or could point me in the direction of benchmark results of the performance of using Sphinx to do search vs. Haystack with a Xapian backend. I'm mainly concerned with full text search on a single field in a single table.

Which of these would be 'faster'? What are the advantages/disadvantages of going with either? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sphinx is one of the fastest out there, but the problem with Sphinx is: an Index update will take you the same time as Building a new Index takes; so if you have a dynamic database and you need to update the Index constantly, Sphinx isn't a good choice and you should go with Xapian or Solr (Lucene)

Speed (query)
Sphinx > Lucene > Xapian

consider dealing with a huge database is different from a medium one. you should read about MySQL full text search, MyISAM, InnoDB, ...

Answer (score 1):

The newest Sphinx (2.0.3) release has real time indexes.